# jQuery Micro Templating

Tags: jquery

After reading [Rick Strahl's blog post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/509108.aspx) I created a few templates myself and I just have one question though. Lets say I return the same JSON object but I want to generate different UI for different purposes (dropdown lists, tables, etc), would I have to create a template for each type of UI or is there a neater solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you want different UIs, and, therefore, different HTML code, how would you do to have only one template?
I think having one template for each type of UI is a good solution, and I don't see any neater one.